# JQuery changing language with window.location.href

Tags: jquery, window.location

I'm trying to change the language on my page with JQuery function by url variable like this...With selecting a value from a dropdown select menu...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#lang_opt").change( function(){
    if ( $(this).val() == "si" ){
        window.location.href = "?lang=si";
    }
    if ( $(this).val() == "en" ){
        window.location.href = "?lang=en";
    }
});
});
```

When I change it to "en" everything works as expected, I'm redirected to mypage.com/index.html?lang=en
But if I change it back to "si" nothing happens...
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I figured out the problem. The default language set in the "dropdown" is always "si". So when I click on "si" again nothing changes and the function is not called. Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: Maybe the simpliest way is to do smth like this http://jsfiddle.net/Gp3tR/ (it will not work on jsfiddle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the `else if` javascript may be it's coming from that position. I've experience many bug from that `if` statement, unless i add `else` at each before i can get my code works perfectly or correctly!

for example:

```
if ( $(this).val() == "si" ){
    window.location.href = "?lang=si";
}
else if ( $(this).val() == "en" ){
    window.location.href = "?lang=en";
}
```

Comment: I found the problem, everytime I change the selection from "si" to "em" JQuery should have to change the default selection on the dropdown. Can't figure out how to do that though....